# ansible correct way of calling + creating the variable

Tags: ansible

I run into a problem and was hoping I could get some help.
I am trying to create a file based on a variable name, that contains a variable.
`app-inputs/app1.yml`

```
---
app_name: "labo.{{ environment }}.eng.inet.com"
environment:
  - int
  - lab
```

when I try to create the file:
`roles/buld_config/tasks/main.yml`

```
---
- name: create destination file
  file:
    path: "{{ folder_path ~ item[0] }}/{{ item[1] }}.yml"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ config_folders }}"
    - "{{ app_name }}"
```

I encounter the following problem:
`"msg": "file (/etc/scripts/app-configs/[].labo.eng.inet.com.yml) is absent, cannot continue"`
The variable {{environment}} does not get populated.

I see the problem: nowhere, do i tell them to loop over the environments, but I don't see, how to do this correctly.

The final goal is to create a file for lab in the lab directory, based on a jinja2 template, create the config. Next it would be int environment, etc...

The environments are not fixed and can be different per app, hence they are defined in the `-e @app-inputs/app1.yml` file

I was hoping I could get some help of people more knowledgeable than me with ansible, as it's one of my first attempts.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hey I understand the situation. There are several ways one can resolve this, it also depends on what we would be achieving by ansible.

So from the above situation, I could suggest one small simple solution. But, like I said there are several ways one can do it, and this is one of them. Maybe, you will see everyone contributing to this question.

**Here is one solution:**

`app-inputs/app1.yml` variables would look like

```
---
app_name: "labo.eng.inet.com"
environment:
  - int
  - lab
```

`roles/buld_config/tasks/main.yml` your task would look like

```
---
- name: create destination file
  file:
    path: "{{ item[0] }}/{{ item[2] }}.{{ item[1] }}.yml"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ config_folders }}"
    - "{{ app_name }}"
    - "{{ environment }}"
```

Hope this helps, but this is some what looks like hack. I can suggest some more based on your comment.

**Update**

Based on the comment here is the updated answer, again there are several ways one can achieve this.

`app-inputs/app1.yml` variables would look like

```
---
app_name_lab: "labo.eng.lab.inet.com"
app_name_int: "labo.eng.int.inet.com"
#I am aware environment is a reserved keyword in ansible, use your own word.
environment: 
  - int
  - lab
```

`roles/build_config/tasks/main.yml` your task would look like

```
---
- name: create destination file
  file:
    path: "{{ item[0] }}/{{ vars['app_name_'+item[1] ] }}.yml"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ config_folders }}"
    - "{{ environment }}"
```

Hope this solves your problem. Again this is not the only possible solution, there are several ways one can achieve this.

Comment: Hi   

thanks for your answer, I have 1 question; I don't see how this would work, if the "{{ environment }}" variable was somewhere else in the name.  
  
eg: labo.eng."{{ environment}}".inet.com for example. These are not actual fqdn's just for illustration.  
  
Would you have any pointers in that direction?

Comment: on a sidenote, to correct myself: don't use "environment" as variable name, it's reserved (I ran into this), so just as a reference, should someone run across this post. your playbook will not work. I changed this to env, now.

Comment: @Sybie Like you said it's also just for illustration based on the question you posted, it doesn't mean I would use `environment` as a variable :). But if you replace `environment` with something else it would work. But again that's the problem, I have posted the updated answer based on your comment, let me know for any issues.

Comment: thanks again for your (prompt and updated) answer! The environment remark, was more for my sake and novices like me, as I was unaware of this, hence, it was in my vars file.


To summarize your answer: there is no way to make this dynamically in ansible?


I am atm tinkering around with replace and register to see if i can make something this way